# BigQuery return Unknown error after create table name with '_ads` suffix

Tags: google-bigquery

[image]

1. I try both API and GUI to create this empty table and they both failed.
2. I create many tables via API just fine but only this name `organizes_ads` has a problem.
3. Same create process and schema can create `organizes_ads_0` but not `organizes_ads`.
4. If I try to get this table via API it will return.

```
{"error":{"code":-1,"message":"A network error occurred, and the request could not be completed."}}
```

I tend to use this name because it's a replicated table name from other source, so it will be weird if I have to hard code to use other name for workaround.

[UPDATE] I also found that any table name with suffix `_ads` will be broken (so nothing wrong with schema).

[image]

Comment: Do you have an AdBlocker enabled in the browser? It could blocking the request with the `ads` word.

Comment: I created a table with _ads suffix, when enabled the AdBlocker in chrome, got the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error could be caused by an AdBlocker.

I created a table with `_ads` suffix and when enabled the AdBlocker I got the same error: `Unknown error response from the server.`

Comment: how this answer is accepted if the issue is repeatable by API? how AdBlocker can affect API calls?

Comment: @SaeedMohtasham If he is making the API request from the browser, using a rest client extension or the [bigquery docs page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/get), the AdBlocker will block it as well. Since the author accepted the answer, I think this was the case.

Comment: To add some more evidence, I was just having this issue on a BigQuery View. If you are using uBlock origin, you can open the dashboard, go to Trusted Sites, and add the entry: console.cloud.google.com